# iOS: Localize the application independent of iPad Language setting

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, localization, internationalization

I am developing one application in which I have to give the language setting option inside the application. My question is, if I set the French language from the iPad setting and after that If I set the Japanese language from app setting then how my app will know that Text should convert to Japanese? Or how can I make my app setting independent of iPad setting. Can I use the localisation feature to do so? or I have to make my own logic to develop this.

Using localisation in above scenario can convert the text in French but my internal language setting is Japanese. So I want it to display the Japanese text.

Please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch your app Language when iPad lanaguge setting  change, use `NSLocalizedString`.

If you want your app language independent from iPad Language setting, use `AMLocalizedString` by [aggressive-mediocrity](http://aggressive-mediocrity.blogspot.sg/2010/03/custom-localization-system-for-your.html)

Answer (score 1):

I use a nice macro (#define) to select a localized string using the French language:

```
#define LocalizedFR(...) NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(__VA_ARGS__, nil, [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fr" ofType:@"lproj"]], @"")
```

and then instead of `NSLocalizedString` I use `LocalizedFR('Cancel')` to display Cancel in French

Of course you can change "fr" to any language, or convert it into a function and pass the language code as parameter.